# Открыть таб при переходе по ссылке с якорем

Tags: javascript

подскажите, каким образом открывать табы при переходе по ссылке c якорем? Например, есть ссылка site.ru/catalog#tab2, при переходе по этой ссылке должна быть открыт таб с #tab2. Табы сделаны на бутстрапе

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Женская обувь</a> 
</li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Мужская обувь</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          Каталог 1
      </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade">
          Каталог 2
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = window.location.href;// Берем ссылку
  var regex = /#(\w+)/gi;
  match = regex.exec(text);// Находим в ней все, что находится после знака #
  if(match)// Если нашел
  {
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('in active');// Удаляем все активные табы
    $('#'+match[1]).addClass('in active');// Добавляем класс 'in active' к ид у которого название с ссылки совпадает с ид у таба
  }
});
```